# free mySQL management studio

Tags: mysql

This is my first question in this area

I am looking for a good free mySQL management studio.

I wonder if there is any thing as good as SQL Server Management Studio

I tried mySQL workbench but is not good and has bugs.

Any other tool you may know?

Comment: Welcome aboard :-)   Can you please explain `Server Management Studio`, or add a link to an explanation. And can you please explain what is wrong with the very excellent MySQL workbench ? I have used it for many years and had no problems. If you want us to recommend something, then you have to list the features you require, state a budget and an operating system, as described in [ask]

Comment: What about the web-based [phpmyadmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin).  Do you want a tool that can draw ER diagrams (phpmyadmin can't do that AFAIK)? What do you need exactly?

Comment: I am looking for a tool similar to MS SQL Server Management Studio, a desktop software that has nice user interface and bugs free